Export Python file with Pyinstaller does not work
I'm trying to export my project using PyInstaller so I can use my app outside of VS Code. I've been trying to get this to work all day, but I keep encountering errors. The error I'm currently getting is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 407, in from_name
StopIteration

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "streamlit/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 384, in exec_module
  File "streamlit/version.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 987, in version
  File "importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 960, in distribution
  File "importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 409, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for streamlit
[PYI-46881:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Proces voltooid]

Can someone help me with this?

After downloading streamlit with pip (https://pypi.org/project/streamlit/), include it in your pyinstaller command, as an argument --copy-metadata streamlit

Or better, specify --recursive-copy-metadata as an argument.
